# why mysql_commit is so slow?

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm a new one used MYSQL.

The codes is:

```
void gdns_mysql::commit_task()
    {
        if (mysql_commit(conn) != 0)
        {
            throw_trackerr_str(boost::format("MysqlCommitError %d %s") % mysql_errno(conn) % mysql_error(conn));
        }
    }
```

This function commit_task is always spending 6~7 seconds.
I want to know why this happen ?
please list some reasons. Thank you

By the way:
The queries is like:

```
void gdns_mysql::update_server_status(std::string const& server_, std::string const& status_)
    {
        stringstream sql;
        sql << "update server";
        if (!status_.empty()) sql << " set status = '" << get_escape_string(status_) << "'";
        else sql <<" set status = status_predict";
        sql << " where serverip = '" << get_escape_string(server_) << "'"
            << endl;
        execute(sql.str());
    }
```

And

```
zone_ptrs_t  gdns_mysql::query_zone_bykey(std::string const& zonename_)
    {
        string statement = "select * from zone";
        bool where_flag = false;
        if (!zonename_.empty())
        {
            statement += " where zonename = '" + get_escape_string(zonename_) + "'";
            where_flag = true;
        }
        select(statement);
        return fetch_datas<zone_t>();
    }
```

Comment: Give some background on the queries you are running. The db might have to rebuild lots of indexes, or perform too much tasks for a single transaction.

Comment: just some add, del, insert operates.And the table is always simple.Thank you.

Comment: **some add, del, insert operates**, these aren't always that simple as you are assuming. Check out your query plans, indexes, joins to pin down the problem point.

Comment: Well, usually RDBMS perform "add, del,  insert operates" but do that on table with millions of rows, with many indexes on text fields, and you are screwed. You can not expect someone to help you without more specific information.